# Android studio does not make new activity or fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.0

i have already tried these

1. delete build and invlide restart does not work.
2. delete gradle folder of android studio
3. i unistall android studio reinstall it work fine for one or two days but it know doing again

Answer (score 0):

Increase heap memory may be it will work.

Step :- open Android Studio > Help (from main menu bar) > Change memory settings > increase to 1920 mb.

and restart your system.